# CQ5 JCR Journal Observation?

Tags: adobe, aem, jcr

Where the Journal log are stored in cq5 server and is it implicitly configure or it has to be configure explicitly as asynchronous observation ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In CQ v5.5 and later, excluding AEM6, the default journal implementation for clustering is stored under crx-quickstart/repository/tarJournal.  Observation doesn't rely directly on the journal.
In the latest version of CQ, AEM6 (rebranded as AEM "Adobe Experience Manager") there is no journal stored in the default repository configuration.

To observe changes to nodes and properties you can implement a listener that is triggered on changes in the JCR.  This is done by implementing the interface `javax.jcr.observation.EventListener` and registering the class with the ObservationManager.  See this article for details on how to do this:
http://experiencedelivers.adobe.com/cemblog/en/experiencedelivers/2013/08/observation_in_jcr.html
http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/2.0/12_Observation.html
http://wemcode.wemblog.com/create-jcr-event

Note that JCR event listeners will work in all released versions of CQ5 and AEM6.x.